# executing any program in mc ends putty session if not logged in with root

Tags: permissions, putty, mc

Maybe there is a simple-obvious solution for this but I dont know how to make mc to be able to execute programs when I press enter/double click on it and I am not logged in as root... the executable has executable rights for all.

I get this whenever I try to execute anything by hiting enter or double clicking or trying
to call a program from the command line. When I run the program to be executed with sudo it opens it up nicely, but I like the pressing enter method and would not like to type always the file name. Or how could I setup only some executables to execute from mc?

Here is my `/etc/mc` folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 121 root root 12288 Nov 14 10:59 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 12278 Aug 22  2010 cedit.menu
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  788 Aug 22  2010 edit.indent.rc
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  247 Aug 22  2010 edit.spell.rc
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Oct 15 10:50 extfs
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1024 Aug 22  2010 filehighlight.ini
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  226 Aug 22  2010 mc.charsets
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 17353 Aug 22  2010 mc.ext
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  7936 Aug 22  2010 mc.keymap
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  7936 Aug 22  2010 mc.keymap.default
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  7913 Aug 22  2010 mc.keymap.emacs
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1979 Aug 22  2010 mc.lib
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  9556 Aug 22  2010 mc.menu
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 10126 Aug 22  2010 mc.menu.sr
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  6259 Aug 22  2010 Syntax
```

The mc from `/user/bin`

```
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root      988432 Aug 22  2010 mc
```

For example, here is a file I would like to execute through mc with normal
user:

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root hUSERS  205780 Jun 11 16:03 DBU3L
```

These are the putty log's last lines:

```
[44m*DBU3L[23;3H[1;1H[39m[49m[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K
[K[1;80H[?1002l[?1001r[?1l>[24;1H(B[m[39;49m
[K
[?1049l>[?47l8[m$ ./DBU3L
```

`mv -v` output:

```
GNU Midnight Commander 4.7.0.2
Virtual File System: tarfs, extfs, cpiofs, ftpfs, fish, mcfs, smbfs
With builtin Editor
Using system-installed S-Lang library with terminfo database
With subshell support as default
With support for background operations
With mouse support on xterm and Linux console
With internationalization support
With multiple codepages support
Data types: char 8 int 32 long 64 void * 64 off_t 64 ecs_char 8
```

I saw in a forum a program called `sam` that could be used to solve the problem, but would
not like to reinvent the wheel if this could be fixed by changing some
rights or mc parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the user launching `mc` didn't had /bin/bash as its init script but a scpecific script. To keep the init script that is used I had to add into it this little bit of code to enable `mc` to execute:

```
mc=`ps $PPID | grep mc`
if [ ! -z "$mc" -a "$mc"!=" " ]
then
    if [ ! -z "admin" ]
    then
        bash $1 $2 $3 $4 $5
        exit
    fi
fi
```

This looks up if `mc` is launched and if it is, it lets the user's `mc` to execute commands with it's pass it over to bash mechanism - allows it only if the user is in an administrators group.